# Why does this code print a garbage value?

Tags: c, scope, initialization

This code snippet was taken from an online C Programming Quiz.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sOZ7l2it2I

Please help me understand this code. Apparently it prints a garbage value. Here we have a local variable var, which hides the scope of the global variable var. I assumed that the local variable var is initialized with the value of the global variable var, the rvalue of the global var is copied into the local var. I understand that from that point on, the name var in the code now refers to the local var. So printing the local var should also print 5. But this is not the case. The program prints a garbage value. This means that the local var was uninitialized or some kind of error happened during initialization of the local var. What is going on here? Is this an issue of undefined behavior?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int var = 5;
int main() {
  int var = var;
  printf("%d", var);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grossly speaking, your `int var = var;` inside `main` is *equivalent* to :

```
int var; // this var is now in the current scope but is uninitialized
var = var; // assign the garbage value from var to var.
```

So the global `var` is ignored, and the local `var` keeps its garbage value (since it is assigned to itself).

Read about [lexical scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping). Check the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (notably its §6.2.1).

BTW, a good enough compiler might warn you, if you ask for all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/); actually it does not for gcc 8 on Debian/Linux ...).

As a rule of thumb, better give longer and descriptive names to global variables, and always avoid naming local (block-scope) [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) like global or static (file-scope) ones.

Regarding [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), read [Lattner's blog](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) and be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of UB.

Comment: So the garbage value in var is assigned to itself?

Comment: @Galaxy That step is likely to be optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: Exactly. it's assigned to itself!